# Retrieve Xml identical nodes C#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I am unable to get the identical XML nodes from the following XML file. I don't understand why this code

```
XmlNodeList xList = xmlRespDoc.SelectNodes("/FCUBS_BODY/Cust-Account-Full/Txn-Profile");
```

is returning NULL. What I wanted to do is, retrieve all the identical nodes `<Txn-Profile>` and put in in a string array or list. I think I am missing something here to retrieve my desired output.

Please suggest.

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <S:Header>
    <work:WorkContext xmlns:work='http://oracle.com/weblogic/soap/workarea/'>rO0ABXekABx3ZWJs</work:WorkContext>
  </S:Header>
  <S:Body>
    <QUERYCUSTACC_IOFS_RES xmlns='http://fcubs.ofss.com/service/FCUBSAccService'>
      <FCUBS_HEADER>
        <SERVICE>FCUBSAccService</SERVICE>
        <OPERATION>QueryCustAcc</OPERATION>
        <SOURCE_OPERATION></SOURCE_OPERATION>
        <MSGSTAT>SUCCESS</MSGSTAT>
        <ADDL/>
      </FCUBS_HEADER>
      <FCUBS_BODY>
        <Cust-Account-Full>
          <Txn-Profile>
            <TXN_CODE>CHD</TXN_CODE>
            <NO_OF_TXN>5</NO_OF_TXN>
            <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>100000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
            <TOTAL_AMOUNT>150000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
            <TXN_DESCUI>Cash Deposit1</TXN_DESCUI>
          </Txn-Profile>
          <Txn-Profile>
            <TXN_CODE>CHW</TXN_CODE>
            <NO_OF_TXN>8</NO_OF_TXN>
            <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>150000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
            <TOTAL_AMOUNT>200000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
            <TXN_DESCUI>Cash Withdrawal1</TXN_DESCUI>
          </Txn-Profile>
          <Txn-Profile>
            <TXN_CODE>DCL</TXN_CODE>
            <NO_OF_TXN>5</NO_OF_TXN>
            <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>100000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
            <TOTAL_AMOUNT>200000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
            <TXN_DESCUI>Deposit By Instruments (Clearing)</TXN_DESCUI>
          </Txn-Profile>
          <Txn-Profile>
            <TXN_CODE>DFR</TXN_CODE>
            <NO_OF_TXN>1</NO_OF_TXN>
            <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>100000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
            <TOTAL_AMOUNT>100000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
            <TXN_DESCUI>Deposit Of Foreign Remittance </TXN_DESCUI>
          </Txn-Profile>
          <Txn-Profile>
            <TXN_CODE>DFT</TXN_CODE>
            <NO_OF_TXN>5</NO_OF_TXN>
            <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>100000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
            <TOTAL_AMOUNT>200000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
            <TXN_DESCUI>Deposit By Instruments (Internal FT)</TXN_DESCUI>
          </Txn-Profile>
          <Txn-Profile>
            <TXN_CODE>WCL</TXN_CODE>
            <NO_OF_TXN>5</NO_OF_TXN>
            <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>80000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
            <TOTAL_AMOUNT>100000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
            <TXN_DESCUI>Withdrawal By Instruments (Clearing)</TXN_DESCUI>
          </Txn-Profile>
          <Txn-Profile>
            <TXN_CODE>WFT</TXN_CODE>
            <NO_OF_TXN>5</NO_OF_TXN>
            <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>50000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
            <TOTAL_AMOUNT>100000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
            <TXN_DESCUI>Withdrawal By Instruments (Internal FT)</TXN_DESCUI>
          </Txn-Profile>
        </Cust-Account-Full>
        <FCUBS_WARNING_RESP>
          <WARNING>
            <WCODE>ST-SAVE-023</WCODE>
            <WDESC>Record Successfully Retrieved</WDESC>
          </WARNING>
        </FCUBS_WARNING_RESP>
      </FCUBS_BODY>
    </QUERYCUSTACC_IOFS_RES>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

My code is:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument xmlRespDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlRespDoc.LoadXml(@"D:\xmlData.xml");

    XmlNodeList xList = xmlRespDoc.SelectNodes("/FCUBS_BODY/Cust-Account-Full/Txn-Profile");

    if (xList != null)
        foreach (XmlNode node in xList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerXml);
        }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Cust-Account-Full>
  <Txn-Profile>
    <TXN_CODE>CHD</TXN_CODE>
    <NO_OF_TXN>5</NO_OF_TXN>
    <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>100000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
    <TOTAL_AMOUNT>150000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
    <TXN_DESCUI>Cash Deposit1</TXN_DESCUI>
  </Txn-Profile>
  <Txn-Profile>
    <TXN_CODE>CHW</TXN_CODE>
    <NO_OF_TXN>8</NO_OF_TXN>
    <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>150000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
    <TOTAL_AMOUNT>200000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
    <TXN_DESCUI>Cash Withdrawal1</TXN_DESCUI>
  </Txn-Profile>
  <Txn-Profile>
    <TXN_CODE>DCL</TXN_CODE>
    <NO_OF_TXN>5</NO_OF_TXN>
    <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>100000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
    <TOTAL_AMOUNT>200000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
    <TXN_DESCUI>Deposit By Instruments (Clearing)</TXN_DESCUI>
  </Txn-Profile>
  <Txn-Profile>
    <TXN_CODE>DFR</TXN_CODE>
    <NO_OF_TXN>1</NO_OF_TXN>
    <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>100000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
    <TOTAL_AMOUNT>100000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
    <TXN_DESCUI>Deposit Of Foreign Remittance </TXN_DESCUI>
  </Txn-Profile>
  <Txn-Profile>
    <TXN_CODE>DFT</TXN_CODE>
    <NO_OF_TXN>5</NO_OF_TXN>
    <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>100000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
    <TOTAL_AMOUNT>200000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
    <TXN_DESCUI>Deposit By Instruments (Internal FT)</TXN_DESCUI>
  </Txn-Profile>
  <Txn-Profile>
    <TXN_CODE>WCL</TXN_CODE>
    <NO_OF_TXN>5</NO_OF_TXN>
    <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>80000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
    <TOTAL_AMOUNT>100000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
    <TXN_DESCUI>Withdrawal By Instruments (Clearing)</TXN_DESCUI>
  </Txn-Profile>
  <Txn-Profile>
    <TXN_CODE>WFT</TXN_CODE>
    <NO_OF_TXN>5</NO_OF_TXN>
    <MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>50000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
    <TOTAL_AMOUNT>100000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
    <TXN_DESCUI>Withdrawal By Instruments (Internal FT)</TXN_DESCUI>
  </Txn-Profile>
</Cust-Account-Full>
```

Comment: The reason is simply: you're **totally ignoring** the defined **XML namespace** - see here: `<S:Envelope xmlns:S='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>` - there's a XML namespace declared and used - you need to **respect that** and use it when selecting from that XML !

Answer (score 2):

You can use **LINQ to XML** in this manner:

`var profiles = XElement.Load(new StreamReader(xmlFileStream)).Descendants("Txn-Profile");`

where `xmlFileStream` is the **FileStream** of the xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it via elements tag name like this:

```
 XmlNodeList xList = xmlRespDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Cust-Account-Full");
```

Comment: I am having output like this. Why this output having xmlns? <Txn-Profile xmlns="http://fcubs.ofss.com/service/FCUBSAccService">
<TXN_CODE>CHD</TXN_CODE>
<NO_OF_TXN>5</NO_OF_TXN>
<MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>100000</MAX_TXN_AMOUNT>
<TOTAL_AMOUNT>150000</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
<TXN_DESCUI>Cash Deposit1</TXN_DESCUI>
</Txn-Profile>

Comment: @SajidWasim that is how it is when using getting the OuterXml of an XmlNode. Its up to you to remove it manually, there is a lot of ways out there.

Comment: Thanks. I have understood.